# Front – Admin & Dashboard Template

Tags: bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there a way to download and try this template before buying

**Front – Admin & Dashboard Template**

https://themes.getbootstrap.com/product/front-admin-dashboard-template/

Comment: Nope, you can use the LivePreview or just contact the seller and see what he says

Comment: Unfortunately, the only option is to buy. Sure you can use tools like wget, but this is not the honest way to get what you want)